# Is it possible to export a Linkedin profile?

Tags: linkedin, export

Is it possible to perform a full export of a complete Linkedin profile?

I want to make several changes, and I'd like to have a "backup" of sorts, just for the sake of keep my data and not lose it.

I don't care about the output format (namely, I don't necessarily need a PDF), what matters to me is to have a backup of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was easier than I expected, the process is described [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/50191?lang=en).

> To request a download of your data:
>
> - Click the **Me** icon at top of your LinkedIn homepage.
> - Select **Settings & Privacy** from the dropdown.
> - Click the **Privacy** tab at the top of the page.
> - Under **How LinkedIn uses your data** section, click Change next to Download your data.
>     Note: You may be prompted to sign in.
> - This will take you to the **Download your data** page where you can select which data you want to download
>
> Within minutes, you'll receive an email with a link where you can
>   download certain categories of personal information we have for you,
>   including your messages, connections, and contacts. This is
>   information that's fastest to compile.
>
> Within 24 hours, we'll send you a second email with a link where you
>   can download your full archive, including your activity and account
>   history.